# Is it possible to get the contents of a loaded .net assembly as a byte array or stream?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies

Is it possible to get the contents of a loaded .net assembly as a byte array or stream?

What I'm trying to do is something similar to (of course the real scenario is much more complex, so just storing the buffer is not an option).

```
byte[] bytes = GetTheBytes();
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(bytes);
byte[] bytes2 = GetAssemblyAsByteArray(asm);
Assert.IsTrue(bytes.SequenceEqual(bytes2));
```

I need to know how to implement the GetAssemblyAsByteArray function.

Edit:
The solution with File.ReadAllBytes() is not good enough because the assembly might be dynamic, and no, I don't have (easy) access to the source (it's automatically generated and I'd prefer not to keep track of it). The comment with serialization might work, but I wouldn't know exactly how to use it. My end goal is to pass the assemblies as /reference options to csc.exe, and the only way I have thought of which works equivalently whether assemblies are dynamic or not is to save all needed assemblies to temporary files.

Comment: Is it sufficient to serialize the assembly to a binary stream (or array)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assembly.Location);
```

on an already loaded assembly and it will get you a `byte[]` that is suitable to be passed to [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx).

**However**, if the assembly was originally loaded using the `Load(byte[])` method, its `Location` property will be an empty string, meaning that this method will not work.

It doesn't look like there is a method of doing what you want for *all* assemblies. The obvious workaround it to store the original `byte[]` when you first get it.

Comment: Actually, reading Location of a dynamic assembly will not return an empty string, but will throw. And the web says there's no way to find out whether the assembly is dynamic, so the try/catch is unavoidable in this case prior to .net4.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629799/how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-assembly-object-to-and-from-a-byte-array or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180391/how-to-save-assembly-to-disk