# how to serialize/deserialize an assembly object to and from a byte array

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, system.reflection

Let's say a create an (executable) assembly in memory by
compiling a code string.  Then I want to serialize this assembly
object into a byte array and then store it in a database.  Then later
on I want to retrieve the byte array from the database and deserialize
the byte array back into an assembly object, then invoke the entry
point of the assembly.

At first I just tried to do this serialization like I would any other simple object in .net, however apparently that won't work with an assembly object.  The assembly object contains a method called GetObjectData which gets serialization data necessary to reinstantiate the assembly.  So I'm somewhat confused as to how I piece all this together for my scenario.

The answer only needs to show how to take an assembly object, convert it into a byte array, convert that back into an assembly, then execute the entry method on the deserialized assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *assembly* is more conveniently represented simply as a binary dll file. If you think of it *like that*, the rest of the problems evaporate. In particlar, look at `Assembly.Load(byte[])` for *loading* an `Assembly` from binary. To *write* it as binary, use [`CompileAssemblyFromSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx) and look at the result's [`PathToAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.pathtoassembly.aspx) - then `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` to obtain the binary from the file.

Comment: But what if you do the compilation entirely in memory?

Comment: @Beaker then that's a pain ;p I don't have an immediate answer there, other than "compiling to the temp-folder would be easier here"

Comment: if no one comes up with an in-memory answer within a week then I'll mark this the answer.

Answer (score 5):

A dirty trick to get the assembly bytes using reflection:

```
  MethodInfo methodGetRawBytes = assembly.GetType().GetMethod("GetRawBytes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  object o = methodGetRawBytes.Invoke(assembly, null);
  
  byte[] assemblyBytes = (byte[])o;
```

Explanation: at least in my sample (assembly was loaded from byte array) the assembly instance was of type "System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly". This is an internal class, so it can be accessed only using reflection. "RuntimeAssembly" has a method "GetRawBytes", which return the assembly bytes.

Comment: GetRawBytes no longer exists in newer .net versions (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28132#issue-558436811)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Reflection.Assembly` is `ISerializable` and can simply be serialized like so:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, asm);
```

and deserialization is just as simple but call `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` instead.

Comment: Deserializating it will not produce the same assembly... In other words the size of the memory stream you create does not equal the size of the assembly file.

Comment: @TonoNam Probably not, but they asked specifically about how to serialize the object, which this will do. It doesn't necessarily mean it will be what the programmer expects. Though I would want to test and verify your statement, I think it should produce a functionally identical assembly.

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly implements System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable interface and in its GetObjectData method it serializes its FullName property. When deserializing it loads assembly from its FullName so it works when serializing and deserializing for assemblies known for the appdomain but it's not "serializing an assembly solution".http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,1588

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example:

```
public static byte[] SerializeAssembly()
{
  var compilerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } };
  CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(compilerOptions);

  CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters()
  {
    GenerateExecutable = false,
    GenerateInMemory = false,
    OutputAssembly = "Examples.dll",
    IncludeDebugInformation = false,
  };
  parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

  ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
  CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, StringClassFile());

  return File.ReadAllBytes(results.CompiledAssembly.Location);
}

private static Assembly DeserializeAssembyl(object fromDataReader)
{
  byte[] arr = (byte[])fromDataReader;
  return Assembly.Load(arr);
}



private string StringClassFile()
    {
      return "using System;" +
      "using System.IO;" +
      "using System.Threading;" +
      "namespace Examples" +
      "{" +
      " public class FileCreator" +
      " {" +
      "     private string FolderPath { get; set; }" +
      "     public FileCreator(string folderPath)" +
      "     {" +
      "         this.FolderPath = folderPath;" +
      "     }" +
      "     public void CreateFile(Guid name)" +
      "     {" +
      "         string fileName = string.Format(\"{0}.txt\", name.ToString());" +
      "         string path = Path.Combine(this.FolderPath, fileName);" +
      "         if (!File.Exists(path))" +
      "         {" +
      "             using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))" +
      "             {" +
      "                 sw.WriteLine(\"file: {0}\", fileName);" +
      "                 sw.WriteLine(\"Created from thread id: {0}\", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);" +
      "             }" +
      "         }" +
      "         else" +
      "         {" +
      "             throw new Exception(string.Format(\"duplicated file found {0}\", fileName));" +
      "         }" +
      "     }" +
      " }" +
      "}";
    }
```