# How to save managed .NET assembly from memory as EXE/DLL file

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I would like to know if it is at all possible, and if so - how, to save a dynamically loaded .net assembly (it was loaded from a byte array, not a file) to a file on disk (exe/dll depending on assembly) and be able to use it directly (i.e. if it is exe, it will contain all exe headers and be runnable or at least "reflectable").

Also do the loaded assemblies actually get stored in memory exactly as they appear in files, i.e. all the PE EXE headers, resources, etc, i.e. essentially exe/dll file in memory, or do they get stored in memory differently and so it will not be possible to save some region of memory as dll/exe .net assembly? That is, if I can use analogy from images: you may load jpeg file into memory as a bitmap, where the actual bytes representing the image in memory will be quite different from the actual bytes representing the jpeg file. So is it the same with loading assemblies?

And finally how do I get the memory addresses (pointers) to where the assembly is actually located in process's memory?

Just to clarify: I do not have any access to the initial byte array from which assembly was loaded via Assembly.Load().

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150913/is-it-possible-to-get-the-contents-of-a-loaded-net-assembly-as-a-byte-array-or), but it's not clear from the answer if there may be a way to dump assembly loaded via byte array from memory to a file on disk.

Thank you.

Comment: Just cast the byte array as a stream and save it to disk. As to do they get stored in memory as per the files. Yes and no. The IL is one for one, once JITted though it's all down to the .net framework. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it clearly. I do not have access to byte array. That's the whole point. All I have is a manged assembly loaded into some process's memory, and I know that that assembly was loaded from a byte array (i.e. no corresponding file on disk exists), so the question is: 1) How do I get to that memory? 2) Is that memory in 1-to-1 correspondence with what would be stored in exe/dll file, and 3) How do I save it (for example using 3rd party tool)?

Comment: Never tried that. Assembly has a GetObjectData method which apparently returns a serialisation of all the information necessary to recreate the assembly. Have you thought about things like codebase? Because the assembly you have and the one you save and then load from disk have different sources the framework will mark them as different even though they are exact functional matches. I.e. you could have them both loaded at the same time...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That's not the issue though. I just wanted to clarify in-memory format of the assembly and if it is possible to persist it to disk in its original form (i.e. as it appeared in the original byte array). Loading both of them at the same time, resolving them, comparing sources is not of interest here.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150913/is-it-possible-to-get-the-contents-of-a-loaded-net-assembly-as-a-byte-array-or) but it was not answered fully, and it is still unclear exactly what is possible for assemblies loaded from byte arrays.

Comment: Actually it looked like the answer was clearly no from that. It's a good question though. I can think of more than a few reasons why "you" wouldn't want this to be possible, definitely worth a ponder though.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in thinking about it. Hopefully someone more knowledgeble will provide an answer. After all there are tools that lets you examine proces's entire memory, so if the assembly is stored exactly as it would be in file, then the answer would be yes, it's possible... but the question is... IS the assembly actually stored in memory in that way, or does it get transformed, much like jpeg file may get transformed into a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in .NET, an assembly can consist of multiple modules that physical located in different locations. So it is only possible to save a module in the assembly. Most of time you will only need the main module so you can use [`Assembly.ManifestModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.manifestmodule.aspx) to get it.

[`Marshal.GetHINSTANCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethinstance.aspx) will return the HINSTANCE of the module, which is the base address of the module according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx) article. Although the remarks in MSDN states in-memory modules do not have an HINSTANCE, it seems the method does returns the base address for in-memory modules.

So now we have the base address of the module. The next thing to do is to determining the size of the module. The simplest way to do this is to parse the [Section Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the PE file. For example:

```
Name   | Raw Size | Raw Address
.text  | 0x2000   | 0x400
.rsrc  | 0x400    | 0x2400
.reloc | 0x200    | 0x2800
```

In this case, the size of the module is the maximum Raw Address plus the corresponding Raw Size, that is 0x2A00.

Comment: That method doesn't work with `System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder`. For example, Powershell builds such assemblies in runtime.